# Debugger stepping friendly delay

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, delay

Let's assume we have code which looks like this:

```
WaitForTenSeconds();
//Meanwhile do something in other threads and maybe set eventHappened to true
if (!eventHappened)
{
  FailDueToTimeout();
}
```

**WaitForTenSeconds** can be implemented using simple **Thread.Sleep**
, **await Task.Delay**, **ManualResetEvent.WaitOne** or other similar methods

Now imagine I want to debug another part of the code using breakpoints and code stepping. The problem is, if I break while the delay is being executed, wait for 10 seconds and then continue the execution, then all of these delay implementations will timeout, even if the application was frozen for the most of that time. Quite often that means that you'll have to start the debugging from the beginning.

So, my question is if there is an easy way to have such delay which won't count the paused-in-debugger time?

Note:
One workaround for me is to use the following approach:

```
WaitForTenSeconds()
{
    const int waitStep = 50;
    for (int waitLeft = 10000; waitLeft > 0; waitLeft -= waitStep)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(waitStep)
    }
}
```

but this code still has issues:

- It allows only limited amount of debugger stepping. If the desired amount of delay is small, then the amount of steps is also small as each debugger stepping "eats" whole waitStep timeout
- Code does not look good enough to be left in production

So, are there any better ways?

Comment: One simple idea is to make the delay adjustable, and set it to something like 1 day when debugging.

Comment: That might help in some cases, but quite often such delays are used as a "heartbeat" so if you set the timeout to be too high, then you might drastically change the behaviour of your app - not good, especially during the debugging session.

Comment: Debugging will always screw with timing and timeouts -- if not in your code, then in libraries, kernel network stacks and other places. You can't write code that's debugger-friendly and still transparent, and writing dedicated code runs the risk of forgetting to undo your machinations when you're done debugging (and you may also inadvertently change the very behavior you're trying to debug). For code sensitive to timing, make more use of tracepoints instead -- that is, log what you're interested in at the breakpoint but have the code continue, rather than manually inspecting stuff.